# Push Functions to an array, Convert let to var

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript-6, scope, ecmascript-5

Is it possible to push functions to an array using `var` instead of `let`.  The code I'm looking at is:

```
function slideRightLoop() {
    let work = [];

    for (var n = 1; n < 5; n++) {
        let next = (n + 1 < 5) ? n + 1 : 1;
        let el = document.querySelector(".position_" + n)[0];
        var change = function change () {
            el.classList.add("position" + next);
            el.classList.remove("position_" + n);
        }
        work.push(change);
    }

    work.forEach(function (n) { 
      return n();
    });
}
```

Comment: why doesn't var work for you?

Comment: @terary I think because its block scoped right now on each iteration let gets reassigned and maintains scope. However when I use var I think it gets hoisted and doesn't reassign on each loop.

Comment: `because compatibility` What do you mean by compatibility? If you need to support ancient browsers, you can just run it through Babel. Also, instead of using `querySelectorAll` and selecting the first element in the `NodeList`, just use `querySelector` instead. I'm not seeing the point of putting each function in an array and then executing it - why not just have a loop that executes each block?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Changed to `querySelector` and got rid of the arrow function and changed some vars in there. I just don't know if it is possible to keep this type of silliness with the function pushes to an array that could use `var` or if it just needs to be scrapped and just push elements a regular array on execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put it into https://babeljs.io/repl/ and see what is converted to. The simplest way is to make the loop body a function which accepts all loop variables as arguments:

```
function slideRightLoop(n, work) {
  var next = (n + 1 < 5) ? n + 1 : 1;
  var el = document.querySelector(`.position_${n}`);
  var change = function change () {
      el.classList.add(`position_${next}`);
      el.classList.remove(`position_${n}`);
  }
  work.push(change);
}

function slideRight() {
    var work = [];

    for (var n = 1; n < 5; n++) {
      slideRightLoop(n, work);
    }

    work.forEach(function (n) { 
      return n();
    });
}
```

Comment: This is super helpful. I also noticed the template literals in there so went through and removed those. But yeah thanks for the answer. Also kinda geekin' out rn you rock.

Comment: Ah I overlooked the template literals :D

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want with `var`, you could use a temporary function to create a closure around your `n` and `next` values.

I changed the code a little bit to leave the meaningful part

```js
function slideRight() {
    let work = [];

    for (var n = 1; n < 5; n++) {
        var next = (n + 1 < 5) ? n + 1 : 1;
        let change = function(next, n){
          return function change () {
          console.log(next, n)
        }}
        work.push(change(next, n));
    }
  

    work.forEach(function (n) { 
      return n();
    });
}

slideRight()
```

This should output the desired values